# Ext(cl(A)) subset of EXT(EXT(CL(A)) and EXT(EXT(CL(A)) subset of Ext(cl(A))

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove:

Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$. Then :
a)Ext(cl(A)) subset of EXT(EXT(CL(A))

b)EXT(EXT(CL(A)) subset of Ext(cl(A))

I think both of them are false

Any help with that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in X$ we have $$x\in Ext(A\cup B)\iff $$ $$x\not \in \overline {A\cup B}=\bar A \cup \bar B\iff$$ $$ (x \not \in  \bar A\land x \not \in \bar B)\iff$$ $$ (\;x\in Ext(A)\land x \in Ext (B)\;)\iff$$ $$ x\in Ext(A)\cap Ext (B).$$

So $Ext (A\cup B)=Ext (A)\cap Ext (B)\subset Ext(A)\cup Ext (B).$

For a counter-example to part (b) let $C$ and $D$ be open sets with $C\ne D.$ Let $A= X$ \ $C$ and $B=X$ \ $D.$ Then $Ext(A)=C$ and $Ext (B)=D.$  ....That is, $Ext (A)$ and $Ext(B)$ can be any open sets $C,D,$ and if $C\ne D$ then  $C\cap D\ne C \cup D$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $\text{Ext}(A)$ is the exterior of $A$, as [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_(topology)).

a) Observe that:

\begin{align}
\ (\text{Ext}(A\cup B))^c &=\overline {A \cup B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}\\
\ (\text{Ext}(A) \cup \text{Ext}(B))^c &=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B} \\
\end{align}
Thus $(\text{Ext}(A\cup B))^c \supseteq (\text{Ext}(A) \cup \text{Ext}(B))^c$. Consequently, $\text{Ext}(A\cup B) \subseteq \text{Ext}(A) \cup \text{Ext}(B)$.

b) Our expressions from (a) quickly shows that this isn't  true in general. Try drawing a Venn diagram to visualize better.